# How do i use styled components with dynamic imports

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to find a way to dynamically import an svg Icon that inherits some standard styling. I havn't see anyone else writing about this... so i think i am on the wrong track.

I have tried creating an SVG wrapper in styled components but that gives me a nest of svg > svg > path 
I'm not sure if this is the right idea. 
I want to stay away from using inline styles in case of specificity issues later.

The SVG Icon code <-- using Create React App i am exporting the svg as a default react component

```
export { ReactComponent as default } from './logo.svg';
```

My Icon code <-- the styled.svg is something i would like to merge with the DynamicIcon... is there a way to do something like DynamicIcon as TestStyle? <-- in the documentation the as is used to change the tag type so i don't think this is right?

```
const TestStyle = styled.svg`
  height: 1rem;
  width: 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
`
const Icon: React.FC<IconProps> = ({ name }: IconProps): React.ReactElement => {
  const DynamicIcon = lazy((): Promise<any> => import(`../../assets/icons/${name}.tsx`));
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading ...</div>}>
      <DynamicIcon />
    </Suspense>
  );
};
```

The import is working and displaying but i would like to have the component as a styled component, this will give me access to themeing and dynamically changing the SVG style with props.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*ℹ - My TypeScript foo is weak so will be using vanilla JS below*

You can simply wrap the dynamically loaded component with `styled(DynamicIcon)`.
Reference: [Extending Styles](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#extending-styles) documentation

```
// Instead of 
// const TestStyle = styled.svg`
//   height: ${props => props.size};
//   width: ${props => props.size};
//   display: inline-block;
// `;

const Icon = ({ name, iconSize }) => {
  const DynamicIcon = lazy(() => import(`./icons/${name}.jsx`));
  // ...  Wrap the dynamically loaded component in `styled()`.
  const StyledIcon = styled(DynamicIcon)`
    height: ${props => props.size}px;
    width: ${props => props.size}px;
    display: inline-block;
  `;

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading ...</div>}>
      <StyledIcon size={iconSize} />
    </Suspense>
  );
};
```

⚠ 
But be aware that the above usage of using `prop.size` is not a good idea as it creates a multiple classes per each width/height.
(*I was trying to get around it with `.attrs` but couldn't get it working but I find it outside the scope of this question and leave that to you* )

[image: not good]

Check out the forked demo here.
[image: Edit so.answer.57318028]

And here is how the logo looks wrapped in styled component
[image: working demo]

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer Sung, Never thought of this i have  now looked into creating styled components in a render after seeing the performance hit from your example. I found that the styledIcon will create a new styledIcon every time Icon re renders see here [link](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/faqs#why-should-i-avoid-to-declare-styled-components-in-the-render-method)... i don't think there is a way around this. I don't expect this component to re render so it might be ok. I wonder if its possible to import a styled component directly with Lazy, thanks again

Comment: Thank you for the link. I wasn't aware of such an issue . And if you really need to hack to get it working without generating new classes mentioned in the article, you can "fake" it using `useMemo` with an empty dep. https://codesandbox.io/s/soanswer57318028-bl1y1 Alas, it's still a "hack" as one should never fake the deps

Comment: Hi @Carl if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @Sung, I was thinking of doing something like that but have the deps. Thank you for helping me out so much I really appreciate it.